# Creating column immune references in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a project that I am working on where multiple conditions are checked across all rows and many columns. The issue is that columns are added/removed from the sheet, and, at present, that results in all of my cell(row,column) references being off + outputting incorrect information. I'm wondering if there's a way to make my column references more robust so that they automatically find the correct headers and use them when checking? Would a solution to this problem be able to account for multiple columns containing the exact same header text?

Basically:

1. No blank columns
2. Column headers have repeats (e.g., Column 1 header: "Financials"; Column 15 header: "Financials")
3. Columns are shifting right and left based on adding/removing columns from sheet

Please find a short sample of my current code below with notes:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long

lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 2 To lastRow
    Select Case Cells(i, 14).Value
        Case Is = "Yes"
            Select Case True
                Case Cells(i, 63).Value = 6 And _
                    (IsEmpty(Cells(i, 77)) Or IsEmpty(Cells(i, 93)) Or IsEmpty(Cells(i, 109)) Or _
                    IsEmpty(Cells(i, 125)) Or IsEmpty(Cells(i, 141)) Or IsEmpty(Cells(i, 157))) 
                    Cells(i, 174).Value = "True" '^THESE CELL VALUES ALL HAVE THE SAME COLUMN HEADER TITLE
```

Comment: Are the column headings always present, and the same values? But just in different columns? Is the header row consistent? That is, no blank columns?

Comment: The column heads are always present, and are always the same values, but can be in different columns (e.g., add a new column and now column 2 is 3, 3 is 4, etc). The header row is consistent with no blank columns, though the headers of the columns I need are often duplicated (e.g., Column 1 header: "Financials", Column 9 header: "Financials")

Comment: @pnuts Yes, I believe I can do that.

Comment: Couple of ways although what you suggest is not an ideal design scenario (constant change of mapped environment).  1 - you could write a sub that is called and searches the header names and updates the column variable assignment 2 - Not sure but you could catch the col # at deletion and then re-assign col#s if col # is greater than this, shift them down a number (much like array removal)

Comment: Are the users only deleting columns (and why?) but they are not inserting columns?  You could allow for column data deletion and leave the header there no matter what, don't allow full deletion.

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code deleting, moving and inserting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table is consistent - starting at A1 and occupying a contiguous block - then `Range("A1").CurrentRegion` will reference the table.

You can then use `.CreateNames` to name the columns (that is, using Named Ranges) according to their headings.

```
Dim rngTable As Range
Dim rng As Range

Set rngTable = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

rngTable.CreateNames True, False, False, False
' that is, based on the first row headings

Range("Salary").Select 'prove it works

'if necessary, iterate the cells of the column,
For Each rng In Range("Salary")
    rng.Value = rng.Value + 10
Next 'rng
```

If a column heading is duplicated ("Financial"), though, then you'll be asked to confirm and the second occurrence will overrule the first. (Or you could say "No" and the first occurrence will be named.) In which case, it is preferable that you first correct these duplicate headings.

---

Correcting the duplicate headings is not necessarily straight forward, but something that you should resolve anyway. If it is a specific word "Financials" (or words) that could be duplicated then this makes the task easier. You could count how many occurrences there are, and correct the second, etc., to "Financials2".

Comment: Much better, though, would be NOT to allow users to change headings or move columns around! ;)

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to to assign a `Name` to the column.  Say column **N** has the header "Payments".  First assign the Name "Payments" to that column:

[image]

Then in *VBA* we can code like:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim rng As Range, colly As Long
    Set rng = Range("Payments")
    colly = rng.Column
    For i = 2 To 100
        If Cells(i, colly) = "whatever" Then
            MsgBox "Help"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

The code will continue to work even if you add/remove columns beforre column **N**.